# MYSQL Stored Procedure to select different column data based on connected user's membership

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to create a stored procedure to return a list of IDs and a Computer name for each  that varies based on the connected user's membership of a company, and that company's region, in the format:

```
ID | ComputerName
=================
```

....but I'm really not getting anywhere with it, and would be grateful of any help!

I need the value of ComputerName to be one of NameCompany, NameRegion, NamePublic depending on which Company/Region the logged in user is a Member of:

ComputerNamesTable:

```
ComputerID | CompnayID | NameCompany | NameRegion  | NamePublic
================================================================
1          | 1         | AlicesPC    | MarketingPC | GeneralPC
2          | 1         | BobsPC      | FinancePC   | SpecialPC
3          | 2         | AndysPC     | AdminPC     | ProtectedPC
4          | 3         | JanesPC     | ReceptionPC | GeneralPC
```

User Table:

```
UserID | UserName | MemberofCompanyID
=====================================
 1     | Jim      | 1
 2     | Sally    | 2
 3     | Ann      | 3
```

Company Table:

```
CompanyID | CompanyName | MemberOfRegionID
==========================================
1         | Acme        | North
2         | Sprockets   | North
3         | Arkwrights  | South
```

Ragion Table:

```
RegionID | RegionName
=====================
1        | North
2        | South
```

### Such that:

Select (ID,ComputerName) from "StoredProcedure" for Jim returns:

```
ID | ComputerName
=================
1  | AlicesPC
2  | BobsPC
3  | AdminPC
4  | GeneralPC
```

Select (ID,ComputerName) from "StoredProcedure" for Sally returns:

```
ID | ComputerName
=================
1  | MarketingPC
2  | FinancePC
3  | AndysPC
4  | GeneralPC
```

Select (ID,ComputerName) from "StoredProcedure" for Ann returns:

```
ID | ComputerName
=================
1  | GeneralPC
2  | SpecialPC
3  | ProtectedPC
4  | JanesPC
```

I'm also trying to then add a "OverrideName" table that can amend things for a given user:

OverrideName Table:

```
OverrideID | UserID | ComputerID | OverrideName
======================================================
1          | 3      | 2          | Special-PC-TopFloor
```

So, Select (ID,ComputerName) from "StoredProcedure" for Ann:

```
ID | ComputerName
=================
1  | GeneralPC
2  | Special-PC-TopFloor
3  | ProtectedPC
4  | JanesPC
```

My thought process so far was to build up a result set of

ID, NamePublic

Then overwrite this using NameRegion, where the userid is in the company and the company is in the region.

Then overwrite that using NameCompany, where the userid is in the company.

And finally overwrite that with the data from the override table where entries match the username.

Any help or suggestions appreciated!

Thanks,

Ben